# How to add multiple dependencies at once in maven?

Tags: java, maven

I have about ~50 jars that I need to add to a maven project.

Is there a way to add lots at once, or add automatically instead of going to each one and adding the artifact and group id for each.

Comment: How abt you just unjar them all in a single location. Then jar it to create a single one. Or if you want each jar separately, then just write a small shell/perl/... script to generate the dependency related XML!

Comment: Also if you have like 50 direct dependencies, there is something wrong with your project. You should break it down a bit. If you're talking of indirect dependencies, then maven should take care of it automatically. You don't have to add indirect ones to your pom, maven will pick them up from your dependency's pom.

Comment: You'll typically not depend on ~50 jars, but rather on 3 or 4 (which you put in the dependencies) and those 3 or 4 depend on 4 each and son on.. That's normally how you get to 50... Are you sure you're planning this right?

Comment: @Miquel, in a typical Spring MVC project you've a lot of dependencies already at the start

Comment: Maven is at heart a dependency management tool. If your project needs to have ~50 jars manually imported then you are most definitely doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The point of maven is not to add "jars". The jars live in repositories, and with most jars, they are in the public maven repository.

You simply add metadata about which jars you need in your pom.xml. Therefore you can only do it one-by-one - it is simply text.